# importing OVA files using command line tool using FreeBSD as choice for OS flag

Tags: operating-system, gcloud, freebsd

I'm having trouble spinning up a nozoomi appliance in GCP. I have the OVA file and opening in VirtuBOX indicates it needs FreeBSD 64bit as OS, but I can't select it as a choice in the command line tool.

```
gcloud compute instances import nozomi --os=**FreeBSD** --source-uri=gs://nozoomi/21.0.1-05041735_16B04-standard-guardian.ova
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import) argument --os: Invalid choice: '**FreeBSD**'.

Valid choices are [centos-7, centos-8, debian-8, debian-9, opensuse-15, rhel-6, rhel-6-byol, rhel-7, rhel-7-byol, rhel-8, rhel-8-byol, sles-12, sles-12-byol, sles-15, sles-15-byol, sles-sap-12, sles-sap-12-byol, sles-sap-15, sles-sap-15-byol, ubuntu-1404, ubuntu-1604, ubuntu-1804, ubuntu-2004, windows-10-x64-byol, windows-10-x86-byol, windows-2008r2, windows-2008r2-byol, windows-2012, windows-2012-byol, windows-2012r2, windows-2012r2-byol, windows-2016, windows-2016-byol, windows-2019, windows-2019-byol, windows-7-x64-byol, windows-7-x86-byol, windows-8-x64-byol, windows-8-x86-byol].

C:\Users\JamesRoberts\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>
```

Comment: Not an expert but you have `nozomi` in command, isn't there a typo as `nozoomi`?

Comment: Currently FreeBSD is not supported by the GCP officially. The available OS images can be found in the documentation[1].

I would suggest you raise a Feature Request(FR) using this link[2]. Once you open the link[2], go to -> Compute -> click on ( Create new Compute Engine issue ) and fill all the details.         
[1]. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/import        
[2]. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests